# What do you want us to do? / What do you want we should do?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

Man 1: *We need to do something.*

Man 2: ***What do you want us to do?** We can't do anything.*

Is the emboldened response/question natural and does using "***us***" include Man 1? If not, would "***What do you want we should do?***" work better to include both of them?

Comment: "What do you want we should do?" is not idiomatic in most varieties of English - see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258015/why-doesnt-that-clause-come-after-want/282372#282372 ).  ("Want" generally doesn't take a clause as its object.)

Comment: @rjpond, as your linked answer mentions, "what do you want [someone] **should do**" would not sound strange to me—my grandparents were both second-generation Eastern European Jewish immigrants. It would sound *deliberately* Yiddish but it wouldn't sound wrong. Other uses that don't use "to do" as the following verb would not sound as natural.

Comment: @randomhead That's fair enough.  That's why I said "most" and "generally" and linked to to my answer.  It's interesting though.  I didn't know that "to do" being the following verb made a difference.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this exchange

> Man 1: We need to do something.
>
> Man 2: What do you want us to do? We can't do anything.

Man 1 uses 'we', so 'us' probably includes Man 2. If Man 1 had used 'You', then maybe 'us' includes the unmentioned Man 3 to man *N*. Much depends on context.

'What [do] you want I should do?' is stereotypical of New York Jewish speech (possibly derived from a Yiddish speech pattern). I have heard it described as a a calque (loan translation) of the German *du willst dass ich soll* and of the Yiddish וועלן איך זאָלן/*veln ikh zoln*.

Comment: To add, "What do you want [person] should do" sounds like natural Yinglish to me, not necessarily dated at all. I would say that only "should do" is natural in this construction; other verbs would not be.

Comment: Agreed, but I think it's a moot point whether 'Yinglish' is a language, or even a dialect . I have heard it described as 'English characterized by a lot of Yiddish loanwords', but I don't see any loan words in 'What you want [person] should do?'. You want we should discuss Yeshivish?